# Selecting different arrays using a list of pointers

Tags: array, teensy, pointer

I have different arrays of different sizes, and a list of pointers to the addresses of each array. How do I select each array using the list of pointers, and access it's elements. On Teensy 3.2 board.

```
int * arr_list[3];        
const int arr_sizes[3] = {3,4,5};  // array of the array sizes
const int ar1[3] = {12,2,8};       // arrays of  different sizes
const int ar2[4] = {41,3,6,47};
const int ar3[5] = {9,32,1,5,7}; 

void map_arrays(){          // list of pointers with the addresses of the 
                            // arrays
arr_list[0] = (int*) &ar1;  
arr_list[1] = (int*) &ar2;
arr_list[2] = (int*) &ar3;
}; 

int arr_number = 1;          // select array 
int a = arr_sizes[arr_number];    // the size of the selected array
int *b = arr_list[arr_number];  
int test = 0;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(57600);  //serial monitor 

} 

void loop() {

for (int i=0; i<a; i++) {     // for the selected arr_number iterate and
test = b[i];                  // return the index elements 

}

Serial.println("size =");      
Serial.println(a);
Serial.println();
delay(1000);
Serial.println("index =");     
Serial.println(test);
Serial.println();
delay(500);

 }
```

Comment: You terminate each array appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it right, only fix initialization of test variables:

1. you do not call map_arrays() in setup()
2. you assign uninitialized arr_list item to b

> ```
> const int* arr_list[3];
> const int arr_sizes[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };  // array of the array sizes
> const int ar1[3] = { 12, 2, 8 };       // arrays of  different sizes
> const int ar2[4] = { 41, 3, 6, 47 };
> const int ar3[5] = { 9, 32, 1, 5, 7 };
>
> void map_arrays() {          // list of pointers with the addresses of the
> // arrays
>   arr_list[0] = ar1;
>   arr_list[1] = ar2;
>   arr_list[2] = ar3;
> }
>
> int arr_number = 1;          // select array
> int a = arr_sizes[arr_number];    // the size of the selected array
> const int *b;
> int test = 0;
>
> void setup() {
>
>   Serial.begin(57600);  //serial monitor
>
>   map_arrays();
>
>   b = arr_list[arr_number];
>
>   for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {     // for the selected arr_number iterate and
>     test = b[i];                 // return the index elements
>     Serial.println(test);
>   }
>
>   Serial.println("size =");
>   Serial.println(a);
>   Serial.println();
>   delay(1000);
>   Serial.println("index =");
>   Serial.println(test);
>   Serial.println();
>   delay(500);
>
> }
>
> void loop() {
> }
> ```